# Add XML node to WSO2 DSS and ESB response

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 DSS set up to return data like this:

```
<Products>
   <Product>
      <SKU>12345678910123</SKU>
      <Item>123456</Item>
      <ItemName>My Product Name</ItemName>
   </Product>
</Products>
```

If there is no data to return I simply get the following:

```
<Products xmlns="http://data.mydomain.com/wso2/Products/getSKUinfo"/>
```

I have WSO2 ESB Pass Through Proxy set up to connect to the above service.  When I hit the service in a URL like esbhost.domain.com/services/Products/SKU/12345678910123 I get the above.  What I'd like to do is add a "Status" node (or whatever it's called) to essentially return this:

```
<Products>
   <Status>1</Status>
   <Product>
       <SKU>12345678910123</SKU>
       <Item>123456</Item>
       <ItemName>My Product Name</ItemName>
   </Product>
</Products>
```

If there isn't a match/no data to return I'd like the response to be:

```
<Products>
   <Status>0</Status>
</Products>
```

Is this possible to do in WSO2 ESB?  Or do I need to add something in WSO2 DSS service?

Please pardon me if I'm not using the right terminology.

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done in the ESB. Basically in the "outSequence" of that proxy service, you can simply use the [filter](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Filter+Mediator) mediator, to check  payload using XPath to check whether there isn't a match or no data is there. So from the filter mediator, in their separate paths, you can build up a message using the [enrich](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Enrich+Mediator) mediator   and add the necessary elements you need, like the 0 and so on. So basically in the filter mediator "true" path, you can save the "Product" element in a property, and add it later to the last created element in the message body using enrich. You may want to check out the [ESB samples](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB403/Running+ESB+Samples) to get a feeling on how these mediators work.

Cheers,
Anjana.